# How to convert a tabularx table into longtable in twocolumn class?

Tags: tables, longtable, tabularx, cell

I have created a table. I used template of springer which has a \documentclass[twocolumn] class. the table is shown in the following figure:

[image]

my code :

```
\documentclass[twocolumn]{svjour3}   
    gsave
    newpath
      20 20 moveto
      20 220 lineto
      220 220 lineto
      220 20 lineto
    closepath
    2 setlinewidth
    gsave
      .4 setgray fill
    grestore
    stroke
    grestore
    \end{filecontents*}
    %
    \RequirePackage{fix-cm}
    \begin{filecontents*}{Draft Paper.eps}
    
    \usepackage{booktabs,array,enumitem,ragged2e}
    \begin{document}
    
    \begin{table} [htp]
    
        \setcellgapes{2pt}
        \centering
        \scriptsize
      \makegapedcells
    \begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}
    {| p{0.007\textwidth} | p{0.068\textwidth} | p{0.1535\textwidth} | p{0.1535\textwidth}  |  }  
      \hline
      
    %%%%  
    \multicolumn{2}{|p{0.1\textwidth}|}{  A} & B & C\\ \hline
    %%%%
    
    \multicolumn{2}{|l|}{MADM} & 
     Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. 
    
      & 
     Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. 
    
    \\ \hline 
    
    \multicolumn{2}{|l|}{MADM} & 
     Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. 
    
      & 
     Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. 
    
    \\ \hline 
    
    \multicolumn{2}{|l|}{MADM} & 
     Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. 
    
      & 
     Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. 
    
    \\ \hline 
    
    \multicolumn{2}{|l|}{MADM} & 
     Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. 
    
      & 
     Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. 
    
    \\ \hline 
    
    \multicolumn{2}{|l|}{MADM} & 
     Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. 
    
      & 
     Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. 
    
    \\ \hline 
    
    \multicolumn{2}{|l|}{MADM} & 
     Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. 
    
      & 
     Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. 
    
    \\ \hline 
    \multicolumn{2}{|l|}{MADM} & 
     Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. 
    
      & 
     Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. 
    
    \\ \hline 
    \multicolumn{2}{|l|}{MADM} & 
     Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. 
    
      & 
     Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. 
    
    \\ \hline 
      \end{tabularx}
      \end{table}
    
    
    \bibliographystyle{spmpsci_copy}
    \bibliography{Bibliography}
    
    
    
    \end{document}
```

How to active the auto-break of my table, i mean that I want to replace automatic the part of the table which penetrates the limits to next page as shown in that picture :

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Do *not* use the environment `table` it cannot have a column- or pagebreak. Use in this case package `supertabular`. But remember, that a break is only possible between two tabular lines and *not* inside a tabular line:

```
\documentclass[twocolumn]{svjour3}  
\usepackage{microtype} 
\usepackage{supertabular,booktabs,array,enumitem,ragged2e}
\begin{document}
    
\small
\tablehead{\hline\multicolumn{2}{|l|}{  A} & B & C\\ \hline}
\tabletail{\hline}
\begin{supertabular}
    {| l | p{0.068\textwidth} | p{0.17\textwidth} | p{0.17\textwidth}  |  }  
      \hline
    \multicolumn{2}{|l|}{MADM} & 
     Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has 
     been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a 
     galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book.     
      & 
     Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has 
     been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a 
     galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book.     
    \\ \hline     
    \multicolumn{2}{|l|}{MADM} & 
     Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has 
     been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a 
     galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book.     
      & 
     Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has 
     been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a 
     galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book.    
    \\ \hline    
    \multicolumn{2}{|l|}{MADM} & 
     Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has 
     been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a 
     galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book.    
      & 
     Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has 
     been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a 
     galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book.    
    \\ \hline 
    
    \multicolumn{2}{|l|}{MADM} & 
     Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has 
     been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a 
     galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book.    
      & 
     Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has 
     been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a 
     galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book.     
    \\ \hline    
    \multicolumn{2}{|l|}{MADM} & 
     Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has 
     been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a 
     galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book.     
      & 
     Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has 
     been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a 
     galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book.     
    \\ \hline     
    \multicolumn{2}{|l|}{MADM} & 
     Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has 
     been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a 
     galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book.     
      & 
     Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has 
     been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a 
     galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book.     
    \\ \hline 
    \multicolumn{2}{|l|}{MADM} & 
     Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has 
     been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a 
     galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book.     
      & 
     Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has 
     been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a 
     galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book.     
    \\ \hline 
    \multicolumn{2}{|l|}{MADM} & 
     Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has 
     been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a 
     galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book.    
      & 
     Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has 
     been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a 
     galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. 
\\
\end{supertabular}

\normalsize    
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I wont want to copy the head, i want to use the head  just in start of table .

Comment: Then do not use `\tablehead`. Where is the problem?? Or change it to `\tablefirsthead`

Comment: It didn't work i tried it in overleaf.com

Comment: "It didn't work" is _not_ a useful error description! Overleaf didn't know your documentclass `svjour3`! This works on Overleaf: https://www.overleaf.com/8368536984qgnrfcdmcwqx